# listNextBatchOfObjects() Request Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Does the AWS s3 client make a request when executing listNextBatchOfObjects on an existing listing?  For example:

```
   while (listing.isTruncated()) {
        listing = amazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing);
        final int paginatedObjectCount = listing.getObjectSummaries().size();
        objectCount += paginatedObjectCount;
    }
```

will the amazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing) line make a request to S3 in this case?  If so, is there a way to get the response from this request?

Comment: To be clear, what type of response are you looking for?

Comment: I'm effectively trying to log requests and responses like the example shown here for a putObject request https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/troubleshooting.html#sdk-request-ids but in this case for a listNextBatchOfObjects() request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.  You can construct the response manually so the above code turns into:

```
        ListNextBatchOfObjectsRequest nextBatchOfObjectsRequest = new ListNextBatchOfObjectsRequest(listing);
        listing = amazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(nextBatchOfObjectsRequest);
        S3ResponseMetadata s3ResponseMetadata = amazonS3Client.getCachedResponseMetadata(nextBatchOfObjectsRequest);
        final int paginatedObjectCount = listing.getObjectSummaries().size();
        objectCount += paginatedObjectCount;
```